# Code execution while mousearea pressed qml

Tags: qt, qml

I checked the different mouseArea events in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#pressed-signal) and there is no chance to execute a js function while a mouseArea is being pressed.

As I am not finding a direct way, so I went for this workaround.
I set a [Timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html) to update my panel in case the added bool property `isPressed` of my mousearea is set to true.

**Mouse area:**

```
MouseArea {
        id: myMouseArea
        //pos and size removed. Not relevant
        property bool isPressed: false
        onPressed: {
            isPressed = true;
        }

        onReleased: {
            isPressed = false;
        }
    }
```

**Timer:**

```
Timer {
    id: updatePanelTimer
    interval: 100
    repeat: true
    running: true
    triggeredOnStart: true
    onTriggered: updatePanel()
}
```

**Function:**

```
function updatePanel() {
    if (myMouseArea.isPressed) {
        //run code
    } 
}
```

Is there a more direct way to have a code executed while a mouseArea is being pressed? I would like to know if there is a way to do this whithin the mouseArea itself, mainly if its possible without the need of the timer.

Comment: I do not understand why you don't call the code directly in `onPressed` handler? Is it because you want to call it repeatedly? If so, then I think the timer is correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I want to call the code repeteadly.

Comment: OK, then I see no problem with using timer. I do not know of any other means which would trigger repeatedly in certain intervals some code other than timer.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot

Comment: You can also use Qt.callLater to cause repeated invocations from the event loop. But warning, you can go into a busy loop that will eat the CPU if you don't manage it correctly and put appropriate delays in the right spots. Definitely, a timer is a better approach if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run code only while mouse is in pressed state :

```
  MouseArea {
            id: myMouseArea
            //pos and size removed. Not relevant
            property bool isPressed: false
            onPressed: {
                updatePanelTimer.start()
            }
    
            onReleased: {
               updatePanelTimer.stop()
            }
        }
```